# PGP Public Key expiration GPG

Tags: public-key, gnupg, pgp

I'm in the process of importing a public key from a business partner.  We have always use GPG and never had a problem.

I’m importing this key using:

```
gpg --import "FileName.asc"
gpg: key AC260214: public key " FileName <FileName @ FileName.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Then when I list the public keys I get:

```
pub   2048s/AC260214 2014-09-05 [expired: 1977-07-06]
uid                  FileName < FileName@FileName.com>
```

We can notice the expiration date of 1977.

If I try to encrypt a file with the key, I get:

```
gpg: FileName < FileName@FileName.com>: skipped: unusable public key
gpg: encryption of `/wm/file/workarea/encryptionKeys/TestFiles/Test.txt' failed: unusable public key
```

But when I import the same public key using OpenPGP GoAnywhere I can see a valid expiration date.

[image: screen shot]

I was also able to encrypt a test file.

Is there a bug with gpg and public keys that has a future date of expiration? Usually other public keys I have imported never expire.

GPG Version info

```
-bash-3.2$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.5
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions. See the file COPYING for details.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to dump the public key using http://www.pgpdump.net and see if it shows the expiration date correctly.